# Chinese visa free with 2 passports

Tags: visas, china, dual-nationality, hong-kong

I'm having a layover in Guangzhou in a couple of weeks (a very long layover) and I was looking forward to visiting Hong Kong for the day as I know a few people there. However, I think this means I cannot use the visa free transit period since I am leaving the Chinese mainland and re-entering. However, I have two passports, an Australian one and an Italian one. I was wondering if I could land in Guangzhou, use my Australian passport for the visa free period, enter Hong Kong, then re-enter China with my Italian passport, and use the 24 hour transit time for Guangzhou from Hong kong with the Italian passport? Let me know if this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you even need two passports for this: it sounds like you can structure your trip as two separate legal 24-hr transits, namely X-CAN-HKG and HKG-CAN-Y?  From China's point of view your first transit ends the minute you enter HKG.

Comment: Not directed at your particular situation and not an answer however generally any immigration restrictions on a person are tied to the person, not the passport and hence mixing and matching passports by dual nationals to circumvent such restrictions is not allowed and many times explicitly forbidden.